# In Welcome To Night Vale how spread out is the town?

Tags: geography, welcome-to-night-vale

Welcome to Night Vale frequently talks about "the barrista district" and a number of other parts of town. But there's no way of knowing where they are in relation to eachother and how big the town is. Does anybody have any cannon sources talking about this? I could not find any.

Comment: There are none. The layout of the town (as well as the population, location, etc) is intentionally kept vague. There are some fan made maps on the internet though.

Comment: Mapping Night Vale is complicated by the unusual terrain.  The angle of intersection between March St. and First Dr. (one block over from the Ralph's) is acute but behaves is if it were obtuse.